# Auto populate multiple fields based on dropdown selection of a different table

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

I have two database tables called "client" and "salary_rate". The salary rate table has a foreign key of client_id from the client table.

The client has already added the rate into the salary_rate table. Now I want to display rates on the interface of adding salary for a labourer on addsalary.php script.

I have the following input, "client name", as a dropdown and salary rates inputs from the salary_rate table. When I choose a client name in the dropdown, I want the salary rate input fields to auto populate.

I have tried code I found on the internet, but whenever I select a client, it doesn't auto populate the fields. If possible, please show me a way to achieve this. Thank you.

addsalary.php

```
function getSalaryRates(client_id) {
$.ajax({
url: 'get_salary_rates.php', // the PHP script that retrieves the salary rates
type: 'post',
data: {client_id: client_id},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(response) {
  // fill in the target inputs with the retrieved salary rates
  $('#morning_shift_rate').val(response.morning_shift_rate);
  $('#night_shift_rate').val(response.night_shift_rate);
  $('#overtime_rate').val(response.overtime_rate);
  $('#ot_morning_shift_rate').val(response.ot_morning_shift_rate);
  $('#ot_night_shift_rate').val(response.ot_night_shift_rate);
  $('#ot_morning_ph_rate').val(response.ot_morning_ph_rate);
  $('#ot_night_ph_rate').val(response.ot_night_ph_rate);
},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  // handle errors
  console.log(error);
}
});
}

<select name="client_id" id="client_id" onchange="getSalaryRates(this.value)">
<!-- populate with client names and IDs from your database -->
</select>
<input type="text" name="morning_shift_rate" id="morning_shift_rate">
<input type="text" name="night_shift_rate" id="night_shift_rate">
<input type="text" name="overtime_rate" id="overtime_rate">
<input type="text" name="ot_morning_shift_rate" id="ot_morning_shift_rate">
<input type="text" name="ot_night_shift_rate" id="ot_night_shift_rate">
<input type="text" name="ot_morning_ph_rate" id="ot_morning_ph_rate">
<input type="text" name="ot_night_ph_rate" id="ot_night_ph_rate">
```

get_salary_rates.php

```
<?php
// connect to the database
include ('includes/header.php');

// check for errors
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}

// retrieve the client ID from the POST parameters
$client_id = $_POST['client_id'];

// prepare the SQL statement to retrieve the salary rates
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT morning_shift, night_shift, overtime, ot_morning_shift, 
ot_night_shift, ot_morning_ph, ot_night_ph FROM salary_rate WHERE client_id = ?');

// bind the client ID parameter to the SQL statement
$stmt->bind_param('i', $client_id);

// execute the SQL statement
$stmt->execute();

// get the results
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// fetch the row as an associative array
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();

// close the prepared statement and database connection
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

// return the result as a JSON object
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: I think you need to share a little more information. First, can you confirm that you are getting a response from your AJAX call? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: when i select the dropdown, the other inputs are just blank. it does nothing

Comment: Add `console.log(response)` above the `// fill in the target inputs...` comment line and share what gets logged to the console.

Comment: Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a MySQL problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score -1):

Try This

addsalary.php

`function getSalaryRates(client_id) {
        $.ajax({
                url: 'get_salary_rates.php', // the PHP script that retrieves the salary rates
                type: 'post',
                data: {client_id: client_id},
        success: function(response){
                 },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
                console.log(error);
               }
        }).done(function (data) {
                  var response = $.parseJSON(data);
                  $('#morning_shift_rate').val(response.morning_shift_rate);
                  $('#night_shift_rate').val(response.night_shift_rate);
                  $('#overtime_rate').val(response.overtime);
                  $('#ot_morning_shift_rate').val(response.ot_morning_shift);
                  $('#ot_night_shift_rate').val(response.ot_night_shift);
                  $('#ot_morning_ph_rate').val(response.ot_morning_ph);
                  $('#ot_night_ph_rate').val(response.ot_night_ph);

        });
}

<select name="client_id" id="client_id" onchange="getSalaryRates(this.value)">
</select>
<input type="text" name="morning_shift_rate" id="morning_shift_rate">
<input type="text" name="night_shift_rate" id="night_shift_rate">
<input type="text" name="overtime_rate" id="overtime_rate">
<input type="text" name="ot_morning_shift_rate" id="ot_morning_shift_rate">
<input type="text" name="ot_night_shift_rate" id="ot_night_shift_rate">
<input type="text" name="ot_morning_ph_rate" id="ot_morning_ph_rate">
<input type="text" name="ot_night_ph_rate" id="ot_night_ph_rate">`

get_salary_rates.php

`<?php
    // connect to the database
    include ('includes/header.php');

    // check for errors
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // retrieve the client ID from the POST parameters
    $client_id = $_POST['client_id'];

    // prepare the SQL statement to retrieve the salary rates
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT morning_shift, night_shift, overtime, ot_morning_shift, 
    ot_night_shift, ot_morning_ph, ot_night_ph FROM salary_rate WHERE client_id = ?');

    // bind the client ID parameter to the SQL statement
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $client_id);

    // execute the SQL statement
    $stmt->execute();

    // get the results
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // fetch the row as an associative array
    $data = $result->fetch_assoc();

    // close the prepared statement and database connection
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

    // return the result as a JSON object
    echo json_encode($data);

    //// should output like 
    /*

    {
        "morning_shift": "someval",
        "night_shift": "someval",
        "overtime": "someval",
        "ot_morning_shift": "someval",
        "ot_night_shift": "someval",
        "ot_morning_ph": "someval",
        "ot_night_ph": "someval"
    }

    and nothing else 

    */
        
    ?>`

Your Database Output Fields in json do not match the values you are using in json object Ex: in sql usery you have selected ot_night_ph and in json object you are calling it as  ot_night_ph_rate which do not match

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?